# libXpm package not available Centos 6.9

Tags: centos, centos6, yum

I'm new to centOs.
Im about to use PHP laravel composer and when I perform

```
composer update
```

it's got an error requires ext-gd

then I perform

```
yum install php-gd
```

then its result an error again that it requires libXrpm

like this,

```
Error: Package: php71w-gd-7.1.9-2.w6.x86_64 (webtatic)
           Requires: libXpm.so.4()(64bit)
```

but when I perform

```
yum install libXpm
```

the result is no package available like this

```
No package libXpm available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

FYI I'm using CentOS release 6.9 (Final)

what should I do?

Comment: What repo are you trying to fetch that from ? `remi-repo` provides `php-gd-7.1.2.el6.remi `libXpm` should be provided by the `base` repo.

Comment: what do you mean "base repo". btw I tried to install "php-gd-7.1.2.el6.remi" and  resulted no package available?

Comment: Could you edit your question and include the output from; `yum repolist` that will tell us what you have enabled/configured and we can work from there.